# Define DataTypes explicitly in XML Query for SSRS to recognize from WCF servcie

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, reporting-services

Okay I am stumped on this one as I am not getting the syntax and need a little guidance.  The XML Query structure of SSRS is used to query an xml structure or else a WCF service.  I have it working fine but the data types are NOT what they are defined on the WCF service so I need to convert them AFTER they come over.  Is there any way to do this first somehow?

I assume so as I have seen this MSDN article: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365158%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

But I am lost as my structure is from a generated 'DataContract' I apply to my 'ServiceContract' and I can't negotiate the structure no matter what I try.  I either get it all or nothing.

In the most simplest terms: "How do you explicitly convert a text value to an integer in SSRS with xml query method"?  The core problem is I want to do a matrix report and I can do this:

Row is: 'state'
Column is: 'Adjudication_Type'
Value is: (Expression) =sum(CINT(Fields!Volume.Value))

But that is a workaround IMHO, the data should be what it is DEFINED as in the contract or else have some ability to make it the correct type explicitly when it is defined by the client in SSRS.  I had other issues with WCF to SSRS the other day and also did a workaround in this thread: [QUERY method of Soap request for SSRS and WCF testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798424/query-method-of-soap-request-for-ssrs-and-wcf-testing)

So let's run through my creation and implementation

1. I created an entity model in .NET 4.5 using Entity Framework 5 in C# in a library project to keep it isolated for the model portion of the data.  The base model generated from the t4 for the data is a class modeled like so:

   ```
   public partial class fMonthlyImpactedVolume_Result
       {
           public string state { get; set; }
           public string ADJUDICATION_TYPE { get; set; }
           public Nullable<int> Yr { get; set; }
           public Nullable<int> Mn { get; set; }
           public Nullable<int> VOLUME { get; set; }
           public Nullable<decimal> QSI_FEES { get; set; }
           public Nullable<int> ActivityDays { get; set; }
       }
   ```
2. I then created an interface and implementation in a website WCF project to host using an basicHttpBinding as its' own project to keep it isolated from the model.
3. I referenced the Entity Project in the Web Site project and return classes generated from the t4 template(*.tt = like a POCO class generator from my understanding)
4. My Interface is as so:

   ```
   [ServiceContract]
   public interface IReportingService
   {
       [OperationContract]
       List<fMonthlyImpactedVolume_Result> GetMonthlyData(string aStart, string aEnd);

       [OperationContract]
       List<MonthlyType> GetMonthlyData2(string aStart, string aEnd);

   }

   [DataContract]
   public class MonthlyType
   {
       [DataMember(Order = 0)] 
       public string state;

       [DataMember(Order = 1)]
       public string AdjudicationType;

       [DataMember(Order = 2)]
       public int Yr;

       [DataMember(Order = 3)]
       public int Mn;

       [DataMember(Order = 4)]
       public int Volume;

       [DataMember(Order = 5)]
       public decimal QSI_Fees;

       [DataMember(Order = 6)]
       public int ActivityDays;
   }
   ```
5. My implementation of the returns are as follows one for just implementing the model AS IS as a return, another one stating explicit values from a 'Data Contract' so it will not generate nullable types.

   ```
   public List<fMonthlyImpactedVolume_Result> GetMonthlyData(string aStart, string aEnd)
       {
           using (SSRSReportsEntities re = new SSRSReportsEntities())
           {
               DateTime dstart = DateTime.Parse(aStart);
               DateTime dend = DateTime.Parse(aEnd);

               return re.fMonthlyImpactedVolume(dstart, dend, null).ToList();
           }
       }

       public List<MonthlyType> GetMonthlyData2(string aStart, string aEnd)
       {
           using (SSRSReportsEntities re = new SSRSReportsEntities())
           {
               DateTime dstart = DateTime.Parse(aStart);
               DateTime dend = DateTime.Parse(aEnd);

               return re.fMonthlyImpactedVolume(dstart, dend, null)
                       .Select(m => new MonthlyType
                           {
                               state = m.state,
                               AdjudicationType = m.ADJUDICATION_TYPE,
                               Yr = (int) (m.Yr ?? 0),
                               Mn = (int) (m.Mn ?? 0),
                               Volume = (int) (m.VOLUME ?? 0),
                               QSI_Fees = (decimal) (m.QSI_FEES ?? 0),
                               ActivityDays = (int) (m.ActivityDays ?? 0)
                           })
                        .ToList();
           }
       }
   ```
6. I Publish this to my local host on IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 Enterprise under an application to my default site called 'Reporting', the endpoint is:

   http:// (localhost)/Reporting/ReportingService.svc
7. I created another project to my C# solution for the client.  I add two service references.  One for the discovery of the service project to test it on the fly.  And another one for the service once published.  I check the endpoint bindings and they work fine.
8. I test the endpoints on the client and they all work as expected for all three methods on the project and publish references. Great.
9. I go to BIDS and set up the a datasource with endpoint in step 6 for connection of type XML and call it WCF Datasource
10. I am testing the methods of 1 or 2 but they both DO NOT TRANSFER THE TYPES I DEFINE.  That is the problem.

    ```
    < Query>
    < Method Name="GetMonthlyData2" Namespace="http://tempuri.org/">
    < Parameters>
    < Parameter Name="aStart"></Parameter>
    < Parameter Name="aEnd"></Parameter>
    </Parameters>
    </Method>
    < SoapAction>
    http://tempuri.org/IReportingService/GetMonthlyData2
    </SoapAction>
    < ElementPath>
    // From my reading SOMETHING should magically identify types here but I can't get 
    // ANYTHING to work like ./{Volume}, {Volume}, Document{}/{Volume}, Root{}/{Volume}
    </ElementPath>
    </Query>
    ```

Comment: When querying XML data in SSRS you need to provide the data types for each field in the query.

Comment: How and why do people answer questions over two years old with one sentence answers in comments?

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to ensure you are getting data back from this service request with a simple query without attempting to define the data types like below:

```
<Query>
<Method Name="GetMonthlyData2" Namespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<Parameters>
<Parameter Name="aStart">
       <DefaultValue>1/1/2016</DefaultValue>
</Parameter>
<Parameter Name="aEnd">
       <DefaultValue>2/1/2016</DefaultValue>
</Parameter>
</Parameters>
</Method>
<SoapAction>
http://tempuri.org/IReportingService/GetMonthlyData2
</SoapAction>
 <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">*</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

If you are getting data back, you may be able to figure out what the response looks like in fiddler and then attempt to query the correct structure and define the types of each field individually like below:

```
<Query>
<Method Name="GetMonthlyData2" Namespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<Parameters>
<Parameter Name="aStart">
       <DefaultValue>1/1/2016</DefaultValue>
</Parameter>
<Parameter Name="aEnd">
       <DefaultValue>2/1/2016</DefaultValue>
</Parameter>
</Parameters>
</Method>
<SoapAction>
http://tempuri.org/IReportingService/GetMonthlyData2
</SoapAction>
 <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">
GetMonthlyData2Response/GetMonthlyData2Result/dataItems{state(string)}
</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

One way to figure out this path is by looking at the raw response in fiddler from a good request made to the service. If you have fiddler installed, you can use the WCFTestClient, change your config to use port 8888 in the WCFTestClient on your http endpoint. Make a request in the WCFTestClient. You will see the request in fiddler. Go to the Composer tab in fiddler and drag and drop the successful request into the composer, next click on the Inspectors tab and click on the TextView tab inside inspector. The response envelope will give you an idea of what the element path should look like.